# Is that correct to say "music for any media project"

Tags: grammar, meaning

What would be the best and correct way to say:

1. Music for any media project;
2. Music for every media project;
3. Music for all media projects.

The meaning of the sentence is that a composer offers its music for licensing to use in different projects such as video, film, podcasts, TV, advertising, etc.

And, in addition, is using the word "media" actually OK when referencing those projects (film, video, podcasts, etc.)

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: “projects in any medium”

Comment: "a composer offers *their* music"  (or his music, or her music) but not "its music")